# How to Alias one of the table sql in cakephp 3.6.3

Tags: sql, cakephp

I'm trying to access Contacts. I'm getting below error

`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Contacts'`

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

[Check SQL Query Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxpco.png)

How do I setAlias() in table associations ?

ContactsController.php

```
     public function index()
        {
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Contacts', 'SourceProspects', 'Status', 
    'Secteurs', 'Products']
    ];
    $contacts = $this->paginate($this->Contacts);
    $this->set(compact('contacts'));
    }

public function view($id = null)
    {
    $contact = $this->Contacts->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Contacts', 'SourceProspects', 'Status', 
    'Secteurs', 'Products', 'Leads', 'Accounts']
    ]);

    $this->set('contact', $contact);
   }
```

ContactsTable.php

```
$this->setTable('contacts');
    $this->setDisplayField('name');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Contacts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_type_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Leads', [
        'foreignKey' => 'lead_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('SourceProspects', [
        'foreignKey' => 'source_prospect_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Accounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'account_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Status', [
        'foreignKey' => 'statut_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Secteurs', [
        'foreignKey' => 'secteur_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Accounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Leads', [
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Are you using raw query or ORM ?

Comment: Please do not insert text as images, insert it as actual text, and please show the code that you are using to generate the query, and the configuration of the involved associations. Also please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: ORM although im not very familiar with it

Comment: #ndm The text was considered as spam so I used screen instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in ContractsTable here

```
$this->belongsTo('Contacts', [
    'foreignKey' => 'contact_type_id'
]);
```

in this way cake join the Contacts table with itself so creating a non unique alias

maybe is just a typo and you wanted to do

```
$this->belongsTo('ContactTypes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'contact_type_id'
]);
```

but if you actually want to use that relationship then you have to alias the joined Contacts table

```
$this->belongsTo('ParentContacts', [ // choose your alias here
    'className' => 'Contacts'
    'foreignKey' => 'contact_type_id'
]);
```

so every time you have to refer to the joined table you can do something like

```
'contain' => [
    ..., 
   'ParentContacts', 
 ],
```